# Storing local audio file data across page loads in HTML5

Tags: html, browser, local-storage, html5-audio, fileapi

I am trying to make a webapp that will load a page from a remote server, but allow the user to play audio from files that are on their local drive (not downloaded from the remote server).  I am able to get this to work, but I also need it to save what the user has done for subsequent visits.  For example: the user loads a page, clicks a "choose file" button, selects an mp3, and plays it.  The user then closes the browser, opens it again, returns to the page, and is able to play the same audio without having to select it again.

I understand that the audio playback is separate from the saving of the user's selection, but in this case one seems to dictate the other.

I am able to get the select-and-play functionality to work with this:

```
<html><body>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
        function handleFiles(files){ 
                var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]); 
                document.getElementById('audioPlayer').src = file; 
        }
</script>

<audio id='audioPlayer' controls ></audio> 
<input type='file' id='selectedFile' 
onchange='handleFiles(this.files)' /> 

</body></html>
```

...but I do not know how to store the selected file data in a way that I can automatically load it on the next visit.  What can I use to store that file location (or even the whole file itself if it comes to it) so that I can still play the audio without the user selecting the file again?

I kind of suspect that saving the local file url somehow may not be possible for security reasons, since auto-playing a file from the local file system without user interaction could be bad news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File handles from File open dialog are not recycleable across different page load sessions.

The best you can do this that you copy audio data to a HTML5 localStorage and play it from there. Or upload the data to your server and play it from there.

http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/web-storage/Storage/localStorage

localStorage is limited to few megabytes depending on the browser.

Comment: Bummer, it sounds like there is no workable option for me.  There could be copyright issues with users uploading music so that's out.  The low storage limits on localStorage rule it out as well.  From more reading around it sounds like the FileSystem API would do just what I need here, but it's only in Chrome right now.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Mikko's answer is the correct answer for my question, but I thought I'd share a possible alternative for anyone else who comes across this thread:

The FileSystem API looks like it would perfectly suit my needs in this case, but at the time of this writing, it is only supported in Chrome.  If audio playback is a minor add-on feature to your webapp though, this might be an option to give Chrome users a better experience and other users would just be unaware that they're missing out.

In [this HTML5 Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), the author shows how to use it, including how to copy user-selected files into a local disk sandbox and how to get a url (needed in my case to audio playback) to those files.